# How to fire Marker component events programatically from another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-leaflet

Using React Leaflet, I am trying to fire the Marker component's "click" event from a sibling component. In regular leaflet, this is done using something like below:

```
L.marker(lng,lat).fire('click');
L.marker(lng,lat).openPopup();
```

In the "Results" component, I have a list of results that when clicked, I would like to trigger the Marker component's events on the map.

```
render() { 
<Results tileClicked2={this.tileClicked3.bind(this)} items={this.state.items}></Results>
<Map ref={m => { this.leafletMap = m; }}>
          <TileLayer .../>
             {this.state.items.map((value, index) => {
                return (<Marker>...</Marker>)
             }
```

In my "tileClicked3" function, I am able to log **this.leafletMap**

```
tileClicked3(index){    
    console.log(index);
    console.log(this.leafletMap)
    //I want to do:
    // marker.fire();
    // marker.openPopup(); 
  }
```

Here is the console log when clicked:

[image]

I figure I must be close, but maybe not.

Any advice would be appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by keeping the clicked item index in state and getting the marker item at that index and rendering it.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Map, TileLayer, Marker } from "react-leaflet";
import "./styles.css";

const listData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    text: "Location A",
    lng: 24.960937499999996,
    lat: 38.54816542304656
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    text: "Location B",
    lng: -103.71093749999999,
    lat: 40.97989806962013
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    text: "Location C",
    lng: 76.9921875,
    lat: 24.84656534821976
  }
];

const List = ({ onListItemClick }) => (
  <div>
    <ul>
      {listData.map((aLocation, index) => (
        <li
          key={aLocation.id}
          onClick={e => {
            onListItemClick(index);
          }}
        >
          {aLocation.text}
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  </div>
);

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    center: [51.505, -0.091],
    zoom: 1,
    markerIndex: 0
  };

  handleItemClick = index => {
    console.log("show Marker for", listData[index]);
    this.setState({
      markerIndex: index
    });
  };

  render() {
    const markerItem = listData[this.state.markerIndex];
    const MarkerToShow = <Marker position={[markerItem.lat, markerItem.lng]} />;
    return (
      <div>
        <List onListItemClick={this.handleItemClick} />
        <Map center={this.state.center} zoom={this.state.zoom}>
          <TileLayer
            attribution='&amp;copy <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            url="https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          />
          {MarkerToShow}
        </Map>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

You can find the working code here:https://codesandbox.io/s/mm6nmw9z29

Comment: But how do I trigger the Marker's events like "Marker.openPopup()"

Comment: @MichaelSoriano you can add `Popup` as child component to `Marker`. As shown here:https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/blob/a507318ac06944f4eb79c61a6ca912dafd490e77/example/components/simple.js#L27

Comment: What I'm trying to do is, when the result item is clicked (the list - not the map), I want to trigger the popup. This is what I have so far: 

https://codesandbox.io/s/m7q2x0lrqj

Notice that when you click on a marker - the popup opens fine. But I want the same behavior when the items on the list are clicked. I'm able to recenter the map to the marker, but I can't figure out how to fire the popup open

Comment: @MichaelSoriano you can store marker refs in an array and call `openPopup` on it. Find it here:https://codesandbox.io/s/p73xzl0n17